# GAS: Combine Data from Multiple Google Sheets Documents (Workbooks) in Google Drive into One Workbook

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script, google-sheets, mapping

I have multiple worksheets stored in a folder and what I would like to do is to read through every sheet (Specifically column D and H of every sheet) and append the data to a master file by mapping the columns to rows (The same way Google form does with responses on a google sheet).

The next step is to move the read files into another folder after they are read. I have done some digging and came up with the code below but am having a bit of challenge and will appreciate help to:

(a) Get the column data (D and H) to a single row on the master file.
(b) Move the file copied into a different folder after they are read.

```
function combinesheets() {
  const folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(Copy_Folder_id)
  const filesIterator = folder.getFiles();
  const ws = SpreadsheetApp.openById(Stage_sheet_id);
  const ss = ws.getSheetByName("Project List");
  let combinedata = [];
  while(filesIterator.hasNext()){
    file = filesIterator.next();
    fileType = file.getMimeType();
    if(fileType === "application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet"){
      ssID = file.getId();
      const data = getDataFromSpreadsheet(ssID);
      combinedata.concat(data);
    }
  }
  ss.getRange(2,1,1,combinedata.length).setValues([combinedata]);
}

function getDataFromSpreadsheet(){
  var ss =  SpreadsheetApp.openById(ssID);
  var ws = ss.getSheets()[0]
  var data =  ws.getRange("A1:I" + ws.getLastRow()).getValues();
  data = data.reduce((acc,row) => acc.concat([row[3], row[7]]), []);
  return data;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Get specific columns:

You can use [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to get the values from certain columns to a single array, which can then be added to your spreadsheet row:

```
function getDataFromSpreadsheet(ssID){
  var ss =  SpreadsheetApp.openById(ssID);
  var ws = ss.getSheets()[0]
  var data =  ws.getRange("A1:I" + ws.getLastRow()).getValues();// how do I get the columns I want here (D & H)
  data = data.reduce((acc,row) => acc.concat([row[3], row[7]]), []);
  return data;
}
```

Then, you would need to add this data to your main sheet. Considering that the `data` coming from different spreadsheets might have different lengths, I'd suggest calling [appendRow](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#appendRow(Object)) inside the loop instead of calling `setValues` once outside (since, if all source columns are not the same length, you'd have to modify the resulting arrays to make them the same size; while this can be done and it could improve efficiency, I'm not sure it's worth it, specially if you don't have many spreadsheets):

```
function combinesheets() {
  const folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(Copy_Folder_id)
  const filesIterator = folder.getFiles();
  const ws = SpreadsheetApp.openById(Stage_sheet_id);
  const ss = ws.getSheetByName("Project List");
  while(filesIterator.hasNext()){
    file = filesIterator.next();
    fileType = file.getMimeType();
    if(fileType === "application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet"){
      ssID = file.getId();
      const data = getDataFromSpreadsheet(ssID);
      ss.appendRow(data);
    }
  }
}
```

**If all the columns have the same length**, you can do this instead:

```
function combinesheets() {
  const folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(Copy_Folder_id)
  const filesIterator = folder.getFiles();
  const ws = SpreadsheetApp.openById(Stage_sheet_id);
  const ss = ws.getSheetByName("Project List");
  let combinedata = [];
  while(filesIterator.hasNext()){
    file = filesIterator.next();
    fileType = file.getMimeType();
    if(fileType === "application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet"){
      ssID = file.getId();
      const data = getDataFromSpreadsheet(ssID);
      combinedata.push(data);
    }
  }
  ss.getRange(2,1,combinedata.length, combinedata[0].length).setValues(combinedata);
}
```

Finally, **if all the data coming from the different sheets should be in the same row**, you could do this instead:

```
function combinesheets() {
  const folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(Copy_Folder_id)
  const filesIterator = folder.getFiles();
  const ws = SpreadsheetApp.openById(Stage_sheet_id);
  const ss = ws.getSheetByName("Project List");
  let combinedata = [];
  while(filesIterator.hasNext()){
    file = filesIterator.next();
    fileType = file.getMimeType();
    if(fileType === "application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet"){
      ssID = file.getId();
      const data = getDataFromSpreadsheet(ssID);
      combinedata.concat(data);
    }
  }
  ss.getRange(2,1,1,combinedata.length).setValues([combinedata]);
}
```

#### Move file:

For moving files to another folder, you just need to retrieve the file and the destination folder via [DriveApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app) and then call:

```
const file = DriveApp.getFileById("FILE_ID");
const folder = DriveApp.getFolderById("FOLDER_ID");
file.moveTo(folder);
```

Comment: Many thanks for the response, I have modified the code as suggested but still running into trouble The parameters (String,number,number,number) don't match the method signature for SpreadsheetApp.Spreadsheet.getRange. This happens at `ws.getRangeList(2,1, combinedData.length, combinedData.length [0]).setValues(combinedData)`  The idea is to append everything into the master file including the empty arrays

Comment: @Just Probably you wanted to call `getRange` instead of `getRangeList`? Please note that, for `getRangeList`, you have to provide an array of a1Notations as parameter, so your call cannot work [getRangeList(a1Notations)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getrangelista1notations). Also, have all the columns in the different sheets have the same length? Otherwise, I'd use `setValues` inside the `while` loop or, alternatively, you'll have to modify each inner array to make them all the same length.

Comment: @Just Finally, if you want to have a 2D array, with one for each row, you'll have to use `push` instead of `concat`. In any case, can you clarify (1) should empty values in the columns be ignored?, (2) should the columns `D-H` from each sheet be added to a single row? If you clarify these, I'd be willing to update my answer accordingly.

Comment: Thank you so much, Iamblichus. To answer your query. (1) should empty values in the columns be ignored? `No, should not be ignored` (2) should the columns D-H from each sheet be added to a single row? `Yes, exactly`

Comment: Also, have all the columns in the different sheets have the same length? `Yes, they all have the same length`

Comment: @Just I updated my answer with three possible alternatives, depending on whether all the columns have the same length or not, and whether all the data from the different sheets should be in the same row or not.

Comment: @Just  Thanks for bringing things back into balance. As long as the hard work gets upvoted it's all good. 

Answer (score 1):

You have two questions.

#### How to move a File In Google Drive

You just need the fileID and the FolderID to move to. Both can be seen in the URL when browsing google drive.

[image]

Here's a function to carry it out:

```
function changeLocation(folderToMoveToID,fileID) {
  var destinationFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderToMoveToID);
  var theFileToMove = DriveApp.getFileById(fileID);
  theFileToMove.moveTo(destinationFolder);
}
```

I'll try to answer other question later.

Comment: Got it..How about copying column to row in the master file?

Comment: @Just, might I suggest you reword your question to just be about Folders, and then repost question on arrays? They really are unrelated and I just checked and at the moment there is not a clear "How to change a Google App Scripts change file folder location" question on StackOverflow. Thus... if you reword your title and question to just this issue, you might find your question gets a lot of hits and proves quite useful. If you repost, be sure to send link as I can solve it when I'm not walking (as I am now).

Comment: Got it  PGSystemTeste. Thank you